# Find is not finding the first occurrence of text in second row

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my excel data

[image]

I am trying to find the cell data in row 1 and 2

```
arrCols = Array("APPLE", "ORANGE")
With Sheet1
    For i = LBound(arrCols) To UBound(arrCols)
        Set colHeader = .Rows(1).Find(arrCols(i), , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext, False)
        Debug.Print arrCols(i) & "=" & colHeader.Address
        Set colDiff = .Rows(2).Find("test", , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext, False)
        Debug.Print "test =" & colDiff.Address
    Next
End With
```

This is the current output

```
APPLE=$A$1
test =$D$2
ORANGE=$D$1
test =$D$2
```

As you can see, in row 2, Excel is not finding the first occurrence of searched data. What am I doing wrong and how do I get the first "test" address?

Edit - Even if I comment out the loop and Row1 find, `.Find` for Row2 is still now working correctly.

Expected output

```
APPLE=$A$1
test =$A$2
ORANGE=$D$1
test =$D$2
```

Comment: change xlByColumns to xlByRows

Comment: @Yane - still same result.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij - why is that? I am trying to find 2 different string in two different ranges

Comment: @Pankaj Jaju `.Find` works to find out first occurrence by given criteria so it doesn't matter if you are running in a loop or otherwise. Can you describe the intention of second row output in plain words? One can simply use: `Debug.Print "test =" & colHeader.offset(1,0).Address` to get the cell data on the second row and the same column.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij - I already have mentioned the expected output in my question. As I said, if i am searching in row1, find is returning expected result. But if i search in row 2, it doesnt. If i move the data from first cell in row2 to second cell, it works but that is not a solution.

Comment: @PankajJaju see if the solution suggested below helps you any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modification of your code that should give you desired output.

I have used `After` option in `Find` method.

```
arrCols = Array("APPLE", "ORANGE")
With Sheet1
    For i = LBound(arrCols) To UBound(arrCols)
        Set colheader = .Rows(1).Find(arrCols(i), , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext, False)
        Debug.Print arrCols(i) & "=" & colheader.Address
        Set colDiff = .Rows("1:2").Find("test", .Cells(1, colheader.Column), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext, False)
        Debug.Print "test =" & colDiff.Address
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Your solution is working correctly. Would you be able to tell me why `After` is not required in Row 1, but is must in Row 2 for correct result?

Comment: @PankajJaju I suspect this has to do with default settings of `Find` method which starts from `A1` for first row only. In all other cases, it starts from column 2 and therefore it doesn't catch value in the first column. If you want to test it then try altering your code line in question like `Set colDiff = .Rows(2).Find("test", .Cells(2, 2), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious, False)` and you will see that it is able to pick cell `A2`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the loop will run for the whole range regardles of where it finds “test” first, so it will only output the last occurrence. You could exit loop when item is found the first time if you wsnt first occurrence to be printed.

Comment: The `Debug.Print ...` are inside the loop, not after.

Comment: I am printing both address inside the loop. The Row1 addresses are correct, the issue is with Row2 addresses.